# Can anyone tell the order in which the events of GridView are fired

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to change the color of the last cell of the row depending upon the value in the second last cell of corresponding row.

**What I have tried:**

I Tried putting the color in RowDataBound but my second last cell of the row gets its value after the RowDataBound is finished for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the orderly events of gridview

```
protected void GridView1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_Load");
}
protected void GridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_DataBinding");
}
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_DataBound");
}
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GridView1_RowDataBound");
}
```

Visit [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms993231.aspx) for detailed explanation.

If you're referring to the Page Life Cycle, you can find an overview [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: From the answer i can see that row data bound is the last event fired where the grid view cells get the Values to display. But for my code i want a value from the cell on which my other cell will depend.The Problem is i tried getting the cell's value in row data Bound but it returns NULL value as after row data bound the value is assigned to the cell.  Can u suggest how can i take a cell's value to use it

Answer (score 0):

For your issue , you can use "CellFormatting" event to format your cell data. In CellFormatting event go through your rows and check for your condition and do necessary changes.

An example is given below:-

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value) == 23 ? Color.Green : Color.Red; // Your condition
        }
    }
```